# How to alter a column and change the default value?

Tags: mysql, sql

I got the following error while trying to alter a column's data type and setting a new default value:

```
ALTER TABLE foobar_data ALTER COLUMN col VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL SET DEFAULT '{}';
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL SET DEFAULT '{}'' at line 1

Comment: I don't think you need SET before DEFAULT

Comment: The MySQL syntax allows either to change just the default value (`SET DEFAULT <literal>`) or to replace the full column definition (`<datatype> DEFAULT ... COMMENT ...`, nullable options etc...).

Answer (score 355, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE foobar_data MODIFY COLUMN col VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '{}';
```

A second possibility which does the same (thanks to juergen_d):

```
ALTER TABLE foobar_data CHANGE COLUMN col col VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '{}';
```

Comment: The `column` is optional. You could just use `ALTER TABLE foobar_data MODIFY col VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '{}';` or `ALTER TABLE foobar_data CHANGE col col VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '{}';` and the result will be same.

Comment: what does '{}' do?

Comment: It's the default string the OP was asking for. When you specify no value for this column when inserting a row, the value becomes `{}`.

Comment: Is writing two `col`s next to each other correct? (like this `col col`)

Comment: @Shafizadeh Yes, it is. This provides the possibility to rename a column. First one is original name, second is the new name.

Comment: Don't use this if you need to change only the `DEFAULT` value. This will process all the rows of the table for nothing (very long on huge tables). Use instead `ALTER TABLE <table_name> ALTER COLUMN <column_name> SET DEFAULT <value>` which is instant.

Comment: Well, @dolmen, the question asked for how to "**alter a column's data type** and setting a new default value". So it's not really a reason to downvote, isn't it?

Comment: @dolmen While not strictly related to this exact question, it is important to note that ALTER COLUMN SET DEFAULT only works with constant values, not things like CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

Answer (score 171):

As a follow up, if you just want to set a default, pretty sure you can use the ALTER .. SET syntax. Just don't put all the other stuff in there. If you're gonna put the rest of the column definition in, use the MODIFY or CHANGE syntax as per the accepted answer.

Anyway, the ALTER syntax for setting a column default, (since that's what I was looking for when I came here):

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN column_name SET DEFAULT 'literal';
```

For which 'literal' could also be a number (e.g. `...SET DEFAULT 0`). I haven't tried it with `...SET DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` but why not eh?

Comment: Also current_timestamp wasn't working for me if quoted. I had to use the following: `ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY COLUMN column_name TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp;`

Comment: +1 Best answer for me, because of by that way I don't need to specify the column's type and other things that will not change!

Comment: This is the efficient answer to change only the `DEFAULT` value.

Comment: If you want the default value to be the time of the insert, use `NOW()` or `current_timestamp()` @Malaise @Nereis

Comment: `ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN column_name SET DEFAULT NOW();`  makes syntax error in mysql 8.0.25! Anyone knows why?

Comment: Works for me, accepted answer don't work for me.

Answer (score 45):

If you want to add a default value for the already created column,
this works for me:

```
ALTER TABLE Persons
ALTER credit SET DEFAULT 0.0;
```

Comment: This is the best answer as you do not need to copy the existing field specification.

Comment: FYI this doesn't seem to work with non-constant values e.g. CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

Answer (score 4):

For DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename
 CHANGE COLUMN columnname1 columname1 DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 CHANGE COLUMN columnname2 columname2 DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Please note **double** columnname declaration

Removing DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename
 ALTER COLUMN columnname1 DROP DEFAULT,
 ALTER COLUMN columnname2 DROPT DEFAULT;
```

Comment: Why  double column names?

Comment: ALTER TABLE tablename CHANGE COLUMN oldColName newColName columnDefinitions

Comment: DROP DEFAULT ?? That syntax is totally wrong, did you even test it before posting it here?

Comment: @LeonardLepadatu **double** column_name can be avoided by using **modify**.
*ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY COLUMN columnname1 TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;*

Answer (score 2):

In case the above does not work for you (i.e.: you are working with **new SQL or Azure**) try the following:

1) drop existing column constraint (if any):

```
ALTER TABLE [table_name] DROP CONSTRAINT DF_my_constraint
```

2) create a new one:

```
ALTER TABLE [table_name] ADD CONSTRAINT DF_my_constraint  DEFAULT getdate() FOR column_name;
```

Answer (score 2):

Accepted Answer works good.

In case of **Invalid use of NULL value** error, on **NULL** values, **update all null values to default value** in that column and then try to do the alter.

```
UPDATE foobar_data SET col = '{}' WHERE col IS NULL;

ALTER TABLE foobar_data MODIFY COLUMN col VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '{}';
```

Comment: What i needed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` CHANGE `column_name` `column_name` data_type  NULL DEFAULT '';
```

like this

```
ALTER TABLE `drivers_meta` CHANGE `driving_license` `driving_license` VARCHAR(30) NULL DEFAULT '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this approach:-

ALTER TABLE foobar_data
CHANGE COLUMN col VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL SET DEFAULT '{}';

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).