# MySQL - Remove default value for Datetime field

Tags: mysql, datetime

An existing MySQL table has a DateTime field which is not null and having a Default Value set as '0001-00-00 00:00:00'. Is it possible to Alter this table to remove the default value for the DateTime field ?

Comment: I found this for you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312433/how-to-alter-a-column-and-change-the-default-value

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Yes, you can drop the default using an [`ALTER TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-table.html) statement like this:

```
alter table your_table 
  alter column your_column drop default;
```

Answer (score 8):

To drop the default from multiple datetime columns in a table:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table 
   ALTER COLUMN columnname1 DROP DEFAULT,
   ALTER COLUMN columnname2 DROP DEFAULT, 
   ALTER COLUMN columnname3 DROP DEFAULT,
   ....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change the column and exclude default clause using following query. Here `T1` is table containing default value for column updated and subject. You can simply remove default value as given below:

```
ALTER TABLE `T1` 
CHANGE `updated` `updated` DATETIME NOT NULL,
CHANGE `subject` `subject` VARCHAR(100)
```