# MySQL is yelling syntax error: unexpected 'DEFAULT'

Tags: mysql, syntax

MySQL is telling 
**syntax error: unexpected 'DEFAULT'** 
in my script below.
How come is this?

```
  USE `neoweb`;

 ALTER TABLE `neoweb`.`ActivationRequests` ADD  CONSTRAINT 
`DF_ActivationRequests_CreatedDate` DEFAULT (utc_timestamp()) FOR `CreatedDate`;
```

Comment: In MySQL, CONSTRAINTs are used to define primary keys and foreign keys. You have to state what kind of constraint you want to add before setting a default value to the field. For more info about constraints: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/constraints.html

Answer (score 0):

Oh... `DEFAULT` is not a constraint.

Anyway your syntax seems wrong.

```
ALTER TABLE TABLENAME   
ADD CONSTRAINT [ PRIMARY KEY/ FOREIGN KEY/ UNIQUE/ CHECK ]
```

is the minimum syntax for adding constraint.

You seem to have default value on your column. How to set default value using `ALTER` statement is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11312469/1936024)