# Sentencia ALTER COLUMN nombre_columna SET no funciona en MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

```
ALTER TABLE prueba  ALTER COLUMN nombre SET DEFAULT 13
```

This sentence doesn't work. The answer in phpmyadmin:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SETDEFAULT 13' at line 1

Comment: This is an English speaking website. You would need to translate your question to English.

Comment: aqui tienes escribir en inglés -- here you have to wrizte in english

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to alter a column and change the default value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312433/how-to-alter-a-column-and-change-the-default-value)

Comment: `SETDEFAULT 13` must be typo.

Answer (score 0):

use instead

```
ALTER TABLE prueba CHANGE nombre INTEGER(15);
```

if your column nombre has the type Integer

Comment: Thank you, the problem was the register's type.